# How to establish TLS connection using HSM and OpenSsl

Tags: openssl, tls1.2, smartcard, hsm, opensc

**Background**

I have inherited the task to establish TLS 1.2 connection with server using cryptography token programmatically. The token in question is a read-only - does not allow extraction of private key - smart card. This token have been initialized during manufacture process. Token holds a private key along with certificate.

The token comes with its own PKCS11 module.

I have configured openssl to use said module in engine:

```
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section

[pkcs11_section]
engine_id = pkcs11
dynamic_path = /usr/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so
MODULE_PATH = TOKEN_PKCS11_LIB.so
init = 0
```

I have extracted the certificate from SmartCard and stored in `sc_cert.pem`.

**Issue**

I have tried to establish a TLS connection to server using command line:

```
 openssl s_client -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine -key "pkcs11:id=HEX;type=private" -cert sc_cert.pem -CAfile .../ca_bundle.pem -connect SERVER:PORT -state -tlsextdebug -debug -showcerts
```

Upon executing the previous command I receive following output:

```
engine "pkcs11" set.
PKCS#11 token PIN: 
No private keys found.
PKCS11_get_private_key returned NULL
cannot load client certificate private key file from engine
140540314130072:error:26096080:engine routines:ENGINE_load_private_key:failed loading private key:eng_pkey.c:124:
unable to load client certificate private key file
```

Also, I have tried using [PKCS11 URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7512) variations to specify key element bu to no avail.

To confirm that private key is present on the card I execute the following command:

```
pkcs11-tool -vvv -L --module TOKEN_PKCS1_LIB.so --pin PIN -O
```

The output:

```
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x1): ACS ...
manufacturer:  ...
hardware ver:  ...
firmware ver:  ...
flags:         token present, removable device, hardware slot
token label        : ...
token manufacturer : ...
token model        : ...
token flags        : login required, rng, token initialized, PIN initialized, other flags=0x40
hardware version   : ...
firmware version   : ...
serial num         : ...
pin min/max        : ...
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x1)
Public Key Object; RSA 2048 bits
    label:      LABEL
    ID:         ID_HEX
    Usage:      encrypt, verify
    Access:     none
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
    label:      LABEL
    subject:    DN: ...
    ID:         ID_HEX
Private Key Object; RSA 
    label:      LABEL
    ID:         ID_HEX
    Usage:      decrypt, sign
warning: PKCS11 function C_GetAttributeValue(ALWAYS_AUTHENTICATE) failed: rv = CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID (0x12)

warning: PKCS11 function C_GetAttributeValue(ALWAYS_SENSITIVE) failed: rv = CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID (0x12)

Access:     sensitive
```

**Note** ID_HEX and LABEL of all 3 - public, cert & private - are same values.

**Questions**

It seems that for reasons unknown to me, openssl engine cannot access private key.

How should I configure / call openssl to use my token in TLS 1.2 authnetication(KeyExchange?)?

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Is my key URL the problem?